# cannot access a node.js app started via systemd

Tags: node.js, systemd

I have a node app that I'm trying to start as a service. The app works fine if I start it from the command line like so: `node app.js`. In that case the process looks like: `edoadmin  5003  4980  0 20:39 pts/0    00:00:00 node app.js`, and the app is available from the browser.

If I create a service and enable it (`sudo systemctl enable splitflap.service`):

```
Description=Splitflap app 
Documentation=
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=edoadmin
ExecStart=node /home/edoadmin/projects/splitflap/Split-Flap/app.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The process looks like:

`edoadmin   921     1  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/node /home/edoadmin/projects/splitflap/Split-Flap/app.js`

but when I try to access the web app, I get the following error:

`Cannot GET /` in the browser.